# Passing SQL update query string to SQL Server from other software where update variable values may or not be NULL

Tags: sql-server, string, sql-update, sql-null

I am creating an update query string in Bizagi, that will be passed to SQL Server to be executed.

The update values are taken from a Bizagi form, and may or not be NULL. The string includes boolean, date and string data types. Each field is a variable.

The string works fine if all the fields have a value, but fails if any of them are NULL.

This is how I am building the string:

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE dbo.SupplierProductionScheduleReplies SET OrderReceived = " + bOrderReceived + ", FactoryReadyDate = '" + IsNull(dFactoryReadyDate, "") + "', MVTPNo = '" + IsNull(sMVTPNo, "") + "', LastUpdated = '" + IsNull(dLastUpdated, "") + "' WHERE id = " + iId);

cmd.Connection = connection;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

I have tried simplifying the query to one column:

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE dbo.SupplierProductionScheduleReplies SET FactoryReadyDate = '" + IsNull(dFactoryReadyDate, NULL) + "' WHERE id = " + iId);
```

but using this the code in Bizagi errors, looking for the variable NULL.

The error message is around the formatting of fields, like the date field, as '""' when trying to enter a NULL entry.

I have tried replicating it in SSMS, but because I am not passing in a string from a 3rd party, I don't know how to replicate what I am trying to send.

The result I am after is an update string that can be passed to SSMS that allows for NULL values for all/some of the variables, except iId.

Comment: **WARNING:** Your code is **dangerous**. It is wide open to SQL injection attacks. Always, *always, **always*** parametrise your code. [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](//stackoverflow.com/q/7505808)

Comment: @ThomA funny enough it's probably easier to handle this kind of code with parameters than concats so he isn't even saving time

Comment: Thanks for the warning @Thoma, I will take that onboard and make some changes.

Comment: @ThomA, reading through the link you posted above, it seems like using a stored procedure would sort out the security vulnerability I have created, and also solve the original issue I posted about. Thanks again.

Comment: Using a stored procedure doesn't stop injection, @MickO . Parameterising your code does. A string defined as `"EXEC dbo.MyProc '" + txtValue +';"` is *just* as dangerous.

Comment: OK, thanks - I will look at parameterising the code and using a stored procedure.